# Need suggestions to split components as module and package what is needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, webpack

I have a giant codebase for my project in `ReactJS` right now which includes some 20 modules in the Navbar, which takes up to 25MB when I bundle it.
Now there are multiple clients I am delivering the same code but all of the clients don't want all the modules from the navbar some want 3 some want 4 and some want 12 of them. Now I need to bundle the whole code with the options hiding into the navbar and ship the entire code for just 2 or 3 modules.

Now what I am thinking is shipping the required modules only to the client, for this, I am thinking that I will create the plugin for all the modules and create a base component structure which will be used for every client.

One more thing I am thinking is that in some cases my clients can ask me for adding one more module to there code without changing anything in the delivered one, like just package 2 modules and ship and it can be loaded without any code change. User can even develop custom component and that can be loaded to UI as well.

Any Idea or Suggestion will be appreciated for these two concerns.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code-splitting to solve your first problem. Newer version of React (16.6) [provides `React.lazy()` for dynamic import.](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) There are some other well-known solutions, including [react-loadable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable), CommonsChunkPlugin or SplitChunksPlugin (depending on the version of webpack you are using).

For your second problem of adding modules dynamically, I don't have any useful solution. If the new modules need access to a data resource in existing code (redux data, routing logic or state of any component), they should be included in and bundled together.

Comment: I have already implemented dynamic imports but it is not affecting the bundle size. it is still 25MB. What is doing is loading the chunk at the runtime. But what I need is to reduce the bundle size also,